# what port can use on OpenShift for org.apache.felix.shell.remote?

Tags: osgi, port, openshift, telnet

I would like to use bot web admin and gogo command line interface for Felix on OpenShift.
I can get web admin working, but to log into a running felix I need the remote shell.

I start felix with:

```
java -Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=15000 -Dorg.ops4j.pax.web.listening.addresses=127.7.77.1 -jar bin/felix.jar
```

and it throws:

```
ERROR: Bundle org.apache.felix.shell.remote [7] Error starting file:/var/lib/openshift/xxxxx/app-root/runtime/repo/osgi/felix-framework-4.4.1/bundle/org.apache.felix.shell.remote-1.1.2.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle org.apache.felix.shell.remote [7].)
java.net.BindException: Permission denied
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
```

Any idea how I can get that to work?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are four externally available ports for your OpenShift Online application.  Two web ports 80 (http)/ 443 (https), and two websocket ports 8000 (ws)/8443 (wss).

From the looks of your command you're trying to connect to 15000 which will result in the
`java.net.BindException: Permission denied` error

You could try replacing your `port=15000` and `listening.addresses=` with the proper OpenShift Environment variables (see https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html for more information)